# Как организовать многоуровневый роутинг в Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-routing, angularjs-controller

Начал использовать *angular1* совсем недавно и есть задача организовать роутинг.

Грубо говоря, для интернет-магазина, типа:

```
/catalog/idCategory/idProducts (/catalog/mobile/meizu, /catalog/tv/sony)
```

Переход может быть по всем 3 путям. Допустим, в каталоге у нас все товары. В категориях соответственно товары по категориям и далее уже сам товар.

Почитав инфу, все же склоняюсь к `ui.route`, но никак не могу реализовать данную иерархию. Как я понимаю, для каждой страницы свой контролер.

т.е роутинг должен быть типа:

```
.state('tasks', {
url: "/catalog",
templateUrl: "templates/catalog.html",
controller: "catalogCtrl"
})
.state('catalog.category', {
url: "/catalog/:catalogId",
templateUrl: "templates/catalogCateg.html",
controller: "catalogCategCtrl"
})
.state('catalog.category.details', {
url: "/catalog/:catalogId/:idproduct",
templateUrl: "templates/productPage.html",
controller: "productPageCtrl"
})
```

И в контроллерах мы должны определять `$stateParams` и передавать в `url`.

Может у кого есть опыт данной реализации или интересные примеры, ссылки. Было бы идеально готовый подобный пример. Разобрать смогу. Документацию читал по `ui.route`.

Много чего от туда подчерпнул, но реализовать так и не получается.

Comment: _Переход может быть по всем 3 путям_ - какие пути имеются ввиду?

Comment: @Grundy  /catalog - все товары, /catalog/category - товары из определенной категории, /catalog/category/product - страница продукта, в url, должны быть его категория и id товара

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ui-router` позволяет довольно гибко настраивать какие части куда вставлять, а также как формировать url.

Конкретно для формирования в данном случае, можно применить [nested states](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-and-Nested-Views), каждый из state будет отвечать за свою часть `url` и `view`.

Так как неизвестно в каком виде все должно выводиться в итоге, будем показывать только вид для текущего state

```js
angular.module('app', ['ui.router'])
  .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    //$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/catalog');
    $stateProvider.state('catalog', {
        url: '/catalog',
        template: '<div>Catalog</div>',
        controller: function() {

        }
      })
      .state('catalog.category', {
        url: '/:catId',
        views: {
          '@': {
            template: function($stateParams) {
              return '<div>Category:' + $stateParams.catId + '<ui-view/></div>';
            },
            controller: function() {}

          }
        },
      })
      .state('catalog.category.product', {
        url: '/:pId',
        views: {
          '@': {
            template: function($stateParams) {
              return '<div>Product:' + $stateParams.pId + '</div>';
            },
            controller: function() {}
          }
        }
      });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.6/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.0/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <a ui-sref="catalog">Catalog</a>
  <a ui-sref="catalog.category({catId:10})">Category</a>
  <a ui-sref="catalog.category.product({catId:10,pId:1})">Product</a>
  <br/>View:
  <div ui-view></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Благодарю, то что надо! +

Comment: @bogopodoben, так же можно указывать, чтобы дочерние view показывались внутри родительских, а не заменяли их

Answer (score 0):

```js
.state('catalog', {
url: "/catalog",
  views: {
    catalog:{
        templateUrl: "templates/catalog.html",
        controller: "catalogCtrl",
        controllerAs: "Catalog"
    }
  }

})
.state('catalog.category', {
url: "/catalog/:catalogId",
  views: {
    category:{
        templateUrl: "templates/catalog.html",
        controller: "catalogCategCtrl",
        controllerAs: "Category"
    }
  }
.state('catalog.category.details', {
url: "/catalog/:catalogId/:idproduct",
  views: {
    product:{
        templateUrl: "templates/productPage.html",
        controller: "productPageCtrl",
        controllerAs: "Product"
    },
    resolve: {
        catalogId: ['$stateParams', function($stateParams){
                                return $stateParams.catalogId;
                            }],
        idproduct: ['$stateParams', function($stateParams){
                                return $stateParams.idproduct;
                            }] 
                        }
  }
});

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/catalog');
```

```html
<-- index.php-->
  <div ui-view="catalog"><div>
<-- templates/catalog.html -->
  <div ui-view="category"><div>
<-- templates/catalog.html -->
  <div ui-view="product"><div>
```

В контроллере productPageCtrl добавьте зависимости catalogId и idproduct
маленько подправил. Если первое состояние будет 'catalog', то имеем вложенные состояния.
Можно после (или вместо) url добавить abstract: true,
Тогда переход в это состояние будет запрещен.